# use post_event in trigger in sqlite database like firebird

Tags: sqlite, delphi

using post_event trigger in sqllite
i want to use post_event in trigger in sqlite database like post_event trigger in firebird
i wonder how to use this to send event to delphi application with alert
i try the post_event in firebird and it send note to delphi applicaton but it did not work for sqlite

```
trigger
after update, insert, delete
post_event 'name';
```

throhght the document i foind thaat i have to use special function but i did't find the function file and how to use it?

Comment: Why don't you use Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want POST_EVENT functionality for your Delphi application backed by SQLite.

SQLite does not provide this functionality natively, but a custom extension function can do so.  For example, the commercial products [FireDAC](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/firedac-faq) and [AnyDAC](http://www.da-soft.com/anydac/unified-api.html) register such a function for SQLite backends.  (I don't use either product — that's just what a quick look around the Firebird/Delphi community suggested.)